# armv7s missing from device architecture using xcodebuild and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to understand how building frameworks works more in general. I created a new framework project in Xcode 10 and I can see in Build Settings `arm64 armv7 armv7s` all defined in `Valid Architectures`. When I make a build for Generic iOS Device and use `lipo -info` I get only `armv7 arm64` and no armv7s. I tried to do it from the command line as well:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos -target FrameworkExample ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="BUILD_DIR"
```

I also tried manually passing each architecture

`-arch armv7s -arch arm64 -arch armv7` but I only got armv7 and arm64 again.

I also tried using destination

`-destination generic/platform=iOS`

Same result.

My project's Deployment Target and Framework Targets are both set to 8.0.

Comment: did you find a solution?